# PMF of compound Poisson process?

Tags: distributions, density-function, poisson-process, geometric-distribution, compound-distributions

Can I obtain an analytic expression for PMF of compound Poisson process?

$Y_t = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{X_t} D_i$,

where $X_t \sim \mathcal{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $D \sim \mathcal{Geometric}(\rho)$.

Comment: You need to assume $\{D_i\}$ and $\{X_t\}$ are independent, right?

Comment: @Zhanxiong: Yes, that is assumed indeed.

Comment: @user3817794 One more concern, I guess $X_t \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ instead of $\lambda$, otherwise the notation $t$ looks superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

First, I will simplify your notation and let $Y = \sum_{i=1}^N D_i$ (with the understanding that the sum is zero if $N=0$.) The $D_i$ are iid [geometric random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and $N \sim \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)$, independently of the $D_i$'s. This can be called a compound Poisson-geometric distribution, but is also known as the Polya-Aeppli distribution.

You did not specify which version of the geometric distribution to use, I will assume the *shifted* geometric, with support $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$ and probability mass function
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}   
  \P(D_i=k)= (1-p)^{k-1} p, \quad k=1,2,3,\dotsc
$$ as this choice seems to be the usual one in this context.

There is an R package (on CRAN) for this distribution `polyaAeppli` and the theory behind that package is in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10629360600997371?casa_token=wE254oXOHDIAAAAA%3ATEjjh4gulTLlosxonpjb-YESS8EWmaHTixUzydcIMT7ZBwibKvdm92XK776IAUerpoXxYvx8Knt-wYs), where it is shown that the pmf (probability mass function) is given by
$$
\P(Y=y) = \sum_{k=1}^y e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}(1-p)^{y-k} p^k \binom{y-1}{k-1}
$$ for positive $y$, and $\P(Y=0)=e^{-\lambda}$.  This distribution also has an [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Poisson_distribution).